# Suggestions for cloud storage services

Tags: cloud-storage

I need suggestions for good online cloud storage services for backing up videos and files. The popular ones are Google and Microsoft. I also came across pcloud and icedrive, which provide a lifetime cloud storage plan. That is relatively cheap. But I have read some negative reviews about it like `what if the companies go bankrupt`, also I am not sure how good their service it. So is it a good idea to go for lifetime storage options provided by companies like Pcloud or Icedrive? Any cheaper monthly/yearly plan alternatives to Google and oneDrive?

Comment: Every cloud storage service will be prone to bankruptcy. Maybe you can establish/host your own private cloud https://nextcloud.com/

Comment: When you decide to stor your data in someone's else computer (ie in "the cloud") you always risk that someone suddenly dissapearing or changing policies or doing anything with your files, there is no way around that.

Comment: Besides, the question is off-topic here, it's not asking for a software recommendation.